# Google spreadsheet timeline diagram

Tags: google-sheets, charts, spreadsheet

I've got a spreadsheet that's automatically being populated by a form. But when I try to make graphs out of the data I always get some kind of error...

The timeline diagram should support date/time format, but I've even tried it with just a date format, converting it to decimals using =DateValue(), other graph types, ...

This is a screenshot of the data and error
[image]

The data in the timestamp column is date/time and the data in the time column is a number.
Yet the chart isn't rendering...

```
Timestamp           time
23-12-2020 9:31:44  0.16
23-12-2020 11:06:08 0.75
23-12-2020 11:55:27 0.24
23-12-2020 12:14:30 0.12
23-12-2020 15:18:25 0.73
23-12-2020 17:17:46 0.6
24-12-2020 13:33:49 0.16
24-12-2020 13:51:57 0.01
24-12-2020 15:28:08 1.21
24-12-2020 17:38:36 0.11
24-12-2020 23:40:46 0.15
25-12-2020 11:34:45 0.13
25-12-2020 15:51:53 0.16
25-12-2020 16:08:12 0.06
26-12-2020 11:01:35 0.75
26-12-2020 11:52:03 0.18
26-12-2020 12:24:22 0.15
```

Can anyone help me out here?

Copy of the sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qJrC55_EPcTZ7nMPsscU69MLPVclImjBq3Ij-nG_P7I/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Here you go: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qJrC55_EPcTZ7nMPsscU69MLPVclImjBq3Ij-nG_P7I/edit?usp=sharing

Also added it to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is with your B column. you are using Netherlands locale settings where:

```
0.16 > not number
0,16 > is valid number
```

[image]

now you got two options. you either:

- change locale to United Kingdom or USA
- delete the chart
- select column B and format it as `Number`
- select column A and format it as `Date time`
- create a timeline chart with range A:B

[image]

or you can:

- change dot `.` for comma `,` in B column
- delete the chart
- format B column as `Numbers`
- format A column as `Date time`
- create a timeline chart with range A:B

[image]

Comment: Oh god... It works! Well that was stupid of me. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

This is happening because the locale is not properly defined. Go to `File > Settings` and change `Locale` to your language. This will ensure that Sheets understands your datetime format. You may need to add the data again to be detected properly. If you have the data without formatting, you’ll know that it was read properly because the datetime will be aligned to the right.

### References

- [Set a spreadsheet’s location & calculation settings](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/58515?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en&oco=0)

Comment: Unfortunately this was already the case. It was set to Dutch (my language) and as you can see in the screenshot the data is already aligned to the right. I set the format to automatic just to make sure, but it's still the same.